# How to debug "Error LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file: cannot read" in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, build, linker

I'm trying to compile a file integrating two different hardware related APIs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include "SmarActSI.h"
#include "SmarActSIConstants.h"
#include "SmarActSIConstants_PS.h"

#include "Madlib.h"
```

[image: Files]

I think the `Madlib` is working, at least I'm coding on top of the provided example.
But the `SmarAct` one is giving me some trouble.

At first, it was saying that it couldn't find the `.h` functions used on `.c` -> so I added them to the deppendencies.

[image: Linker deppendencies]

Then it was saying that one of the library `.h` couldn't be found, that was included inside of another `.h` -> so I tried to change the relative include, to an absolute path include, and some variations, and settings.

[image: Additional includes]

For some reason, out of nowhere, I started getting this error:

`Error    LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x5CE6  Example C:\Program Files\Mad City Labs\NanoDrive\C Example\smaractsi.h  1`

I tried to revert every change, but this error doesn't go away.

How do I fix this?

**EDIT:**
From Microsoft's helping center: "LNK1107 can occur if a file passed to the linker or related tools is corrupt. To resolve this issue, rebuild the file."

How can I rebuild if the error doesn't allow me to build?

Comment: Remove the .h files from "Additional Depencencies". You can only put .lib files there. Putting .h files there doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't if this is against TOS, but...: I love you. That was it! Thanks